# How to skip a couple of lines code with lldb?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Is there a way to skip over lines of code while debugging with lldb without having to recompile?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### UPDATE

In addition to the original answer below, the `jump`/`j` aliases can be used for skipping a number of lines or skipping to a specific line number:

To skip two lines ahead:

```
(lldb) jump +2
```

To skip to line 102:

```
(lldb) jump 102
```

See `help jump` for more info.

#### ORIGINAL

This can be achieved using the `thread jump` command by giving the `--by`/`-b` flag. Example:

```
(lldb) thread jump --by 2
(lldb) th j -b 2
```

Alternatively, instead of a relative move an absolute line number can be specific with `--line`/`-l`.

```
(lldb) thread jump --line 102
(lldb) th j -l 102
```

Note that these both move the program counter, and that could put the program into a broken state and lead to crashes.

Comment: I've been able to use this in a small project, but in a large project `thread jump --by 2` throws an exception. I saw this technique in a WWDC 2018 debugging video, as well. Are you aware of any workarounds for larger projects with a lot of threads?

Comment: Addendum to above: I'm able to get it working on the main thread by wrapping in `DispatchQueue.main.async { do stuff }`.